# React Native Bottom Tab not showing up

Tags: react-native, expo

Im currently working on an app using expo and react native.
I am trying to create a bottom navigation tab and encountered an issue where the bottom tab is not showing.

I have tried checking the screens 1 by 1 into the navigation container, and the screen will show but when i changed it to Tabs it doesnt work.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZSBU.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohciJ.png)

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXdTQ.png)

Comment: can you post that code as text rather than an image? Better yet, create a project through https://snack.expo.dev/ and post it on here so we can reproduce your issue to the exact!